# Finding Imageviewer library in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When I using some applications,
I saw good imageviewer such as attached.

When user touch the image in the some post,
it shows total image count in that post.

And it shows thumbnail in the bottom and it can use pinch zoom and sliding.
I trying to find this library in the github but can't find similar library.

Please recommend useful imageviewer library in the swift.

[image]

Comment: Why are you finding library for this? You can develop this on your own. Did you give it a try?

Comment: check this link maybe you can find it: [link](https://github.com/matteocrippa/awesome-swift#images)

Answer (score 2):

I will send you some awesome image viewer libraries.
hop it will help you:

[Agrume](https://github.com/JanGorman/Agrume)

[ATGMediaBrowser](https://github.com/altayer-digital/ATGMediaBrowser)

[AXPhotoViewer](https://github.com/alexhillc/AXPhotoViewer)

[Brightroom](https://github.com/muukii/Brightroom)

[ImageViewer](https://github.com/Krisiacik/ImageViewer)

[SwiftyGif](https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif)

[Viewer](https://github.com/3lvis/Viewer)

[Lightbox](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Lightbox)